# IIS 8.5 Output remaining requests in headers

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8, rate-limiting, ip-restrictions

I am using the 'IP Address and Domain Restrictions' setting on IIS 8.5 to deny IP addresses based on the number of requests over a period of time.

Is is possible to output the remaining number of requests to the HTTP response headers, so users can see how many they have left each time they make a request?

Regards

Comment: IIS does not support that. You might develop your own IIS extension to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds difficult though. Do you have any simple examples to get me started?